# Cannot Connect to MsSql2008 R2 Database Engine, While Connecting to Other Services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication, database, windows-8

I have installed MsSQL 2008 R2 on my computer as I have installed always before. But unfortunately this time, I cannot connect to Database Engine while I can easily connect to the other services like Analysing, Reporting, etc. with the same credentials (Windows Authentication). The only difference is Windows 8, an so if it is not related to it, could you please clarify me where might the problem be?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------
Cannot connect to localhost. (I also tried to us ip and computer name)
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'MyDomain\johnson'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476

Comment: There should be State too. Find the state of error and check details on [Error18456](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the program with different account than you use currently the problem might be related to that. What you can do is to try to follow these steps:

Go to:
Administrative tools > Local Policies > Security Options. Scroll down to User Account Control and make sure that:
"Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode' is disabled".

If the problem still continues after rebooting the computer and trying to connect to MSSQL Server again, it is better to remove and reinstall MSSQL Server again.

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
As you mentioned I moved my computer to domain after installing MSSQL Server and the problem was probably due to that. Because I have installed the same version many times before and I have never seen such a kind of problem. I have uninstalled it and now I am installing again. I think it will solve my problem, but in case it is not I will inform you.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem before, but although I have changed the user settings of the account by assigning it Admin roles, it did not solve the problem. Finally I uninstalled and then reinstalled the software again and solve the problem.